# Counter wont subtract on button press?

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

I am trying to get my setCount to -1 each time the endSetPressed action is called.

I have included setCount -= 1 to the updateTimer function so that when endSetPressed is pressed, it should -1 from the setCount and then start the restCount timer. However in practice it doesnt seem to show it doing the -1 in the app it just stays fixed at the starting setCount value.

Another issue was that I want to be able to see the value of restRemainingCountdownLabel as the user is setting the restStepperValueChanged value, i figured this was done via 'restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(restCount)' however as im using 'restCount = Int(sender.value)*60' to generate a value in minutes, its showing the restRemainingCountdownLabel in seconds rather than mins, Appreciate some guidance on that one too!

Here is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var restRemainingCountdownLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var setsRemainingCountdownLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfSetsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfRestLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var adjustSetsStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var adjustRestStepper: UIStepper!

var restTimer: Timer?
var restCount = 0
var setCount = 0

@IBAction func endSetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(RestController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func setStepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    numberOfSetsLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
    setCount = Int(sender.value)
    setsRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(setCount)
}

@IBAction func restStepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    numberOfRestLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
    restCount = Int(sender.value)*60
    restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(restCount)
}

@IBAction func resetSetsButton(_ sender: Any) {
   //setCount = Int
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func updateTimer() {
    if (setCount > 0){
        setCount -= 1
    }
    if (restCount > 0){
        let minutes = String(restCount / 60)
        let seconds = String(restCount % 60)
        restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        restCount -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: debug your code, use breakpoints and inspect values, add `print(...)` statements.

Comment: ive only been doing swift for a week so im not really knowledgable enough to debug stuff, hence why im here asking for some help

Comment: then get used to debugging, that is the most valuable advice I can and will give you. The problem is probably very easily fixable once you start adding `print`s and breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `updateTimer()` method, first line:

```
if (setCount > 0)
```

if `setCount > 0` then subtract 1 from `setCount`

but...here you've declared `setCount` with a value of 0

```
var setCount = 0
```

So, you never end up in your `if` part :)

#### How to Debug This

The next time you have a problem like this, try adding some `print()` statements to your code.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
@IBAction func endSetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("endSetPressed")
    restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(RestController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func setStepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    numberOfSetsLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
    setCount = Int(sender.value)
    setsRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(setCount)
}

@IBAction func restStepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    numberOfRestLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
    restCount = Int(sender.value)*60
    restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = String(restCount)
}

@IBAction func resetSetsButton(_ sender: Any) {
   //setCount = Int
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func updateTimer() {
    print("updateTimer")
    if (setCount > 0){
        print("setCount > 0")
        setCount -= 1
        print("setCount is now \(setCount)")
    }
    if (restCount > 0){
        print("restCount > 0")
        let minutes = String(restCount / 60)
        let seconds = String(restCount % 60)
        restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        restCount -= 1
        print("restCount is now \(restCount) - minutes: \(minutes) - seconds: \(seconds)")
    }
}
```

That should give you some indications about what is going on and the "path" your code follows.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks this was useful, however if the readout is "updateTimer
setCount > 0 setCount is now 4" how can it be 4 and not be > 0 ? I assumed i was setting setCount earlier on to = the suer defined number as i used the setStepperValueChanged action first to set it higher

Comment: ive managed to fix it using print statements and moving the set -1 up to the @IBAction func endSetPressed(_ sender: Any) code so that its removing 1 earlier on and not on each tick of a timer which didn't make sense! then writing the setcount to the lable after the -1, id just been staring at it too long

Comment: I know that feeling. Sometimes you can stare at something seeming so simple for so long that you go blind :) Glad you got it solved